# What is the most Pythonic way to use an empty dictionary as a default argument?

Tags: python

Using default arguments of the form `x={}` usually does not accomplish the intended purpose in Python, since default arguments are bound when a function is defined, not called.

The convention seems to be to set mutable objects as default arguments with `x=None` and then check `x is None` to assign the proper default when the function is called.

So if I would like to cast `x` to a dictionary that is by default empty, I would use something like the following:

```
def f(x=None):
    x = dict(x) if x is not None else {}
```

However, since `dict` can take any iterable, I could also write this more succinct version:

```
def f(x=()):
    x = dict(x)
```

Which of these is the "right" approach?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *idiomatic* style is to *not* cast to `dict`; that way someone could use *any* object that implements the correct mapping methods.

So, the most pythonic method is to use:

```
def f(x=None):
    if x is None:
        x = {}
```

and then just use mapping methods.

So, you generally should not cast arguments to a dict. You state your API *accepts* a mapping object instead, and expect callers to do the casting.

The only reason to accept both a `dict` and an iterable is when you want to support ordered key-value pairs where duplicate keys are allowed, such as for the [`urllib.urlencode` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode). In such a case a `dict` cannot retain that information, and that method does not cast the iterable to a dict, but rather uses the dict as an iterable.

Answer (score 1):

There's not a right or wrong answer here, but I'd say the first is more idiomatic (that doesn't make the second one wrong, or bad, or worse, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be mentioned that an empty `dict` as an argument is only a problem if the function itself *changes* this `dict`.  In case the `dict` is just read, no problem occurs whatsoever.

And if there is a changing of the `dict` intended, why should an empty `dict` make sense as a default argument?  Since this hasn't been provided by the caller they do not have a reference to this and the changes done to the `dict` are lost after the call.

The only case in which this might make sense is when the function needs to do something for which a changed version of its input is needed.  In such a case the function should probably create the changed version without changing the input directly, for instance:

```
# bad way:
def f(x={}):
  x['newkey'] = 'newvalue'
  print(x)  # do something with the extended x

# probably better way:
def f(x={}):
  new_dict = {}
  new_dict.update(x)
  new_dict.update({ 'newkey': 'newvalue' })
  print(new_dict)  # do something with the extended x
```

In this way (the latter one) the original `x` is never changed, so no problem occurs.

I know that the mutable default argument problem is well-known and accepted to be a problem.  But I also have the feeling that running into it is just a symptom of a more profound problem with the structure of the code it appears in and I wanted to point that out in this post.  Or put the other way:  In a soundly structured piece of code a mutable default argument should never result in an actual problem.